# Switching classes with hover states, maintaining old state for a period

Tags: css, css-animations

I basically have an area which can be selected or deselected by clicking. It has an unselected state, which has a hover state that matches the selected state so the user gets a visual hint about clicking it.

Similarly, when selected, the hoverstate matches the unselected state.

Here's an example with selected being 'green':

```
.clicker { //standard state
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.clicker:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

.green { // selected state
    background-color: green;
}

.green:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

The problem is, when the user clicks, it immediately turns from unselected-hover to selected-hover, so it looks sort of like they unclicked it.

I'd like to have a short period where the item maintains it's old hoverstate, that is, it's unselected (red), I hover and it turns green, I click it, jQuery in the background adds the selected/green state, but nonetheless the area stays green for a second rather than immediately going to selected hoverstate (ie showing red).

I thought about using a simple (non-)animation, something like:

```
@keyframes holdGreen {
    0% {
        background-color: green;
    }
    99% {
        background-color: green;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

And somewhere putting

```
animation: holdGreen
animation-duration: 1s
```

and a similar holdRed for when I click a selected one to unselect.

This would work okay if it were just a class with a hover state, but it doesn't work when totally changing/adding classes which also have hover states.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

something like this could work?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var selected = false;
    $('.clicker').click(function(){
        selected = true;
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
    $('.clicker').mouseout(function(){
        if(selected == true) { $(this).addClass('selectedHover') };
    });
});
```

Then you would have a class that looked something like this:

```
.selectedHover:hover { background: red; }
```

Essentially all that's happening is that the class that controls the hover effect for the item in its "selected" state is only being applied once the users mouse leaves the item after activating it.

basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/KfHPJ/10/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to go with JavaScript workaround. Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/chrisdanek/SK3Vc/ which implements your idea (using webkit prefixes only for the sake of example, so check in Chrome). You'll notice it behaves as intended on click, but there is a problem with default hover action - there is a delay with applying background color.

```
.clicker { width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid; background-color: red; }

.clicker:hover { background-color: green; -webkit-animation-name: holdRed; -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; }

.green { background-color: green; animation: none; }

.green:hover { background-color: red; -webkit-animation-name: holdGreen; -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; }

@-webkit-keyframes holdGreen { 0% { background-color: green; }
  99% { background-color: green; }
  100% { background-color: red; } }

@-webkit-keyframes holdRed { 0% { background-color: red; }
  99% { background-color: red; }
  100% { background-color: green; } }
```